# amsbook+thmtools: `\listoftheorems` points to first page of document, not to list of theorems

Tags: hyperref, amsbook, thmtools

I use the `thmtools` package in an `amsbook` document and compile with `pdflatex`. The hyperlink generated in the table of contents that should point to the list of theorems wrongly points to the first page of the document. A MWE can be found below.

I'm partially able to resolve the problem by adding

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtheoremname}
```

just before `\listoftheorems`. Now the link correctly points to the list of theorems, but the table of contents contains *two* entries to the list of theorems.

I'd be very grateful if someone has hints on how to resolve this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@dotsep{5}
\def\listtheoremname{List of theorems}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{Example}
\author{J. Doe}
\address{Earth}
\email{j.doe@earth.org}

\begin{abstract}
  Bla bla.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{4}

\tableofcontents
\listoftheorems

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

\begin{theorem}
  Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\phantomsection\pdfbookmark{\listtheoremname}{\listtheoremname}` instead of `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: For me a `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\listoftheorems` right after `\tableofcontents` is sufficient. Do you have some 'out-dated' tex distribution?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm using TeXLive 2012, but your suggestion works. I'm not sure why `\listoftheorems` doesn't work out of the box, but if you make it an answer, I'll accept it. And if I use `\pdfbookmark`, I also get the appropriate links in the PDF table of contents!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, `\listoftheorems` from `thmtools` does not add correct hyperlinks, when adding a ToC entry to the List of Theorems. It does also not provide automatic bookmarking for the PDF outline.

Using a `\cleardoublepage` after `\tableofcontents` in conjunction with `\phantomsection` will provide the correct hyperlinking anchor.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@dotsep{5}
\def\listtheoremname{List of theorems}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{Example}
\author{J. Doe}
\address{Earth}
\email{j.doe@earth.org}

\begin{abstract}
  Bla bla.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{4}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark{\listtheoremname}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems


\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

\begin{theorem}
  Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```