# List of Theorems not in pdf readers index

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, amsthm, thmtools

I am using `memoir` and the `\listoftheorems` of the `thmtools` package. And while it seems to beautifully work and integrate in the table of contents, it does not appear in the index listing of the pdf reader (I used `okular`).

Is there a setting to make it appear there?

Here is an MWE creating a list of theorems and a table of contenst. The former appears in the latter, but not in the index of the pdf reader.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\RequirePackage[
hidelinks,
breaklinks=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
bookmarksopen=true
]{hyperref} % not working?

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \listoftheorems

    \chapter{My}
    \begin{theorem}
        My first theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        My second theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \section{Awesome}
    \section{Table}

        \begin{theorem}
            My third theorem.
        \end{theorem}
    \chapter{Of}
    \section{Contents}
    \section{Is}
    \section{Here}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrelated but, you should probably load `hyperref` last

This seems to help:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftheorems}{\@fileswfalse}{}{\typeout{yes}}{\typeout{no}}
```

`thmtools` (through `thm-listof.sty`) defines `\listoftheorems` via a local redefinition of `\listoffigures`. In this definition we find `\@fileswfalse` which in this case causes `List of Theorems` to not be added to the PDF bookmarks (no idea why). At least it comes back if I add the two lines above (after `thmtools`)

Comment: awesome, thanks, it works now! I found the line in `thm-listof.sty` that you mentioned. But I do not understand what your `\typeout`command does. Could you add this shortly to the answer? [The help I found here](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-174.html) just said it prints a message to the terminal and the log file.

Comment: You can remove those. They just write to the log, whether or not the patching went well. Note: don't change anything in `thm-listof.sty`

Comment: And I adjusted my question so hyperref is loaded last.

Comment: @daleif this solution crashes with too many bookmarks, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476924/110154)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\RequirePackage[
hidelinks,
breaklinks=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
bookmarksopen=true
]{hyperref} % not working?

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

   \begingroup
   \phantomsection\pdfbookmark{\listtheoremname}{\listtheoremname}
   \listoftheorems
   \endgroup  

    \chapter{My}
    \begin{theorem}
        My first theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        My second theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \section{Awesome}
    \section{Table}

        \begin{theorem}
            My third theorem.
        \end{theorem}
    \chapter{Of}
    \section{Contents}
    \section{Is}
    \section{Here}

\end{document}
```

Source: [amsbook+thmtools: `\listoftheorems` points to first page of document, not to list of theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201738/amsbookthmtools-listoftheorems-points-to-first-page-of-document-not-to-lis) answer from [@ChristianHupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer)

Comment: Thanks, I also liked the answer and upvoted it. Unfortunately, that will only have an effect when I have more than 15 rep points.

Comment: Wont this fail if the list of theorems is rather long (fail as in point to the wrong page)

Comment: @daleif you are right. But if I reverse the order has much less posibilities to fail. I didn't manage to make it fail... Editing.

Comment: @ciem you have them :)

Comment: @koleygr yes (: