# Too many bookmarks for hyperref and xpatch

Tags: hyperref, xpatch

I use a lot of "Lists of" in my document, some of them are generated by `\listoftheorems`. To include these lists in my PDF-bookmarks, I use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398772/110154).

But actually this crashes, when too many bookmarks are produced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftheorems}{\@fileswfalse}{}{\typeout{yes}}{\typeout{no}}

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents
%\tableofcontents %causes crash
\listoftheorems

text

\end{document}
```

Comment: you get an error also without the patch. Why are you trying to create so many table of contents, is it only for the example?

Comment: Yes, this is only for the MWE.